# How pass the data of a foreach to a modal window?

Tags: php, laravel

This is the code that i have in index.blade.php

```
@foreach ($posts as $item)
  <!-- Someting -->
  <form name="f" method="POST" action="route...">
    @csrf
    @method('DELETE')
    <button class="modal-open"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>
    <!-- Delete button... -->
  </form>
@endforeach
```

How i can open a modal window with the data from `$item` where i clicked the edit button and not the others? (When i tried the code always give me the data of the frist or the last `$item`)

Here the modal window code

```
<div class="modal opacity-0 pointer-events-none fixed w-full h-full top-0 left-0 flex items-center justify-center">
    <div class="modal-overlay absolute w-full h-full bg-gray-900 opacity-50"></div>
    <div class="modal-container bg-white w-11/12 md:max-w-md mx-auto rounded shadow-lg z-50 overflow-y-auto">
        <div class="modal-close absolute top-0 right-0 cursor-pointer flex flex-col items-center mt-4 mr-4 text-white text-sm z-50">
            <svg class="fill-current text-white" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18">
                <path d="M14.53 4.53l-1.06-1.06L9 7.94 4.53 3.47 3.47 4.53 7.94 9l-4.47 4.47 1.06 1.06L9 10.06l4.47 4.47 1.06-1.06L10.06 9z"></path>
            </svg>
            <span class="text-sm">(Esc)</span>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-content py-4 text-left px-6">
            <form name="form" action="route..." method="GET" class="mt-3">
                @csrf
                @method('POST')
                <br>
                <textarea class="bg-gray-300 rounded" name="mensaje" placeholder="{{Here the old data}}" required></textarea>
                <input type="hidden" name="foro_id" value="#">
                <input type="hidden" name="tema_id" value="#">
                <div class="mt-2">
                    <button type="submit" class="bg-green-300 p-1 rounded">Actualizar Post</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div class="flex justify-end pt-2">
                <button class="px-4 bg-transparent p-3 rounded-lg text-indigo-500 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-indigo-400 mr-2">Action</button>
                <button class="modal-close px-4 bg-indigo-500 p-3 rounded-lg text-white hover:bg-indigo-400">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you all and sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Where is your modal code? Maybe put it inside your foreach and give different ids/classes so you can open them or you can manipulate it via javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use JavaScript or JQuery to pass the data to the modal. For my convenience, I am using JQuery. For JQuery, we need to do something like the following-

In index.blade.php

```
<button class="modal-open" data-item-foro-id="{{ $item->foro_id }}" data-item-tema-id="{{ $item->tema_id }}"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>

//In Modal

............
<input type="hidden" name="foro_id" id="foro_id" value="#">
<input type="hidden" name="tema_id" id="tema_id" value="#">
............
```

JQuery Code-

```
<script>
$(document).on("click", ".modal-open", function () {
    var foroId= $(this).attr('data-item-foro-id');
    var temaId= $(this).attr('data-item-tema-id');
    $("#foro_id").val(foroId);
    $("#tema_id").val(temaId);
});
</script>
```

Note: Here, I am providing an example to pass values to the two input fields. If you get the idea from it, you can pass any value to the modal.

Comment: I had problem to  proved it (It is eassy but is my frist time with JQuery) but it work very good, thank! (I accept the answer but i can not vote posts, sorry)